# Style react component on hover

Tags: css, reactjs

i have a grid with img icons i want them to change the background to white if hovered but if a next one is hovered the previous should go to standard background color. I think it should be possible to do it with the useState hook
I think its a pretty beginner question but i didnt find a proper way to do it yet.
Hope you guys can help me.
Thanks in advance :)

```js
// SkillsCard.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./SkillsCardStyle.css";

type SkillsCardProps = {
  skills: {
    name: string;
    header: string;
    text: string;
    url: string;
  }[];
  setSelectedSkill: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>;
};

const SkillsCard: React.FC<SkillsCardProps> = ({
  skills,
  setSelectedSkill,
}) => {
  const [white, setWhite] = useState("");
  const handleAction = (selectedSkill: any) => {
    setSelectedSkill(selectedSkill);
    setWhite(selectedSkill.name);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("white :>> ", white);
  }, [white]);
  return (
    <div className="grid">
      {skills.map((skill, index) => (
        <img
          key={index}
          src={skill.url}
          onMouseEnter={() => handleAction(skill)}
          // className={white ? `${skill.name}` : `${skill.name} active`}
          className={skill.name}
          style={{ color: ` ${white ? "blue !important" : "red"}` }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SkillsCard;
```

```css
.grid {
  margin-left: 5vw;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "HTML . ."
    "css  Bootstrap  Tailwind"
    "JavaScript TypeScript . "
    "React Next ."
    "MongoDB Express Node";

  height: 70%;
  grid-column-gap: 1vw;
  grid-row-gap: 1vh;
}
.grid img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0.4vh solid white;
  padding: 1vh;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid img {
  height: 100%;
}

.HTML {
  grid-area: HTML;
}
.css {
  grid-area: css;
}
.Bootstrap {
  grid-area: Bootstrap;
}
.Tailwind {
  grid-area: Tailwind;
}

.JavaScript {
  grid-area: JavaScript;
}
.TypeScript {
  grid-area: TypeScript;
}
.React {
  grid-area: React;
}
.Next {
  grid-area: Next;
}
.MongoDB {
  grid-area: MongoDB;
}
.Express {
  grid-area: Express;
}

.Node {
  grid-area: Node;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store either the index or a unique id of the "active" (last hovered) card. Then from there add an `onMouseEnter` handler to each card that updates the state, and add a class to the active card that styles it how you want. Using the index it would look like this:

```js
const [activeCard, setActiveCard] = useState(-1);

return (
  <div className="grid">
    {skills.map((skill, index) => (
      <img
        key={index}
        src={skill.url}
        onMouseEnter={() => setActiveCard(index)}
        className={skill.name + (activeCard === index ? " active" : "")}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

**Original answer:**

You don't really need to use react state for this. The simplest approach would be to use a css :hover selector. In your case the following will do the trick:

```css
.grid img:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: Im sorry you probably understood me wrong.
I want the img to stay white until the next one is hovered.

Comment: @Synav Just edited my answer to show an approach for each image to remain hovered until the next one is hovered. This [codepen](https://codepen.io/stephen-oleary/pen/PoLjdNK) has a functioning example